# Pandas multi-index subtract from value based on value in other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

Given the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('A', 'a'): [23, 'n/a',54,7,32,76],
    ('B', 'b'): [23, 'n/a',54,7,32,76],
    ('possible','possible'):[100,100,100,100,100,100]
    })
df
    A       B   possible
    a       b   
0   23      23      100
1   n/a     n/a     100
2   54      54      100
3   7       n/a     100
4   32      32      100
5   76      76      100
```

I'd like to adjust 'possible', per row, for every instance of 'n/a' such that each instance will subtract 4 from 'possible'. 
The desired result is as follows:

```
    A       B   possible
    a       b   possible
0   23      23      100
1   n/a     n/a     92
2   54      54      100
3   7       n/a     96
4   32      32      100
5   76      76      100
```

Then when that's done, I want every instance of 'n/a' to be converted to 0 so that the column type is integer (but float will do).

Thanks in advance!

Follow-up question:

What if my multi-index is like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        ('A', 'a'): [23, 'n/a',54,7,32,76],
        ('A', 'b'): [23, 'n/a',54,7,32,76],
        ('B', 'b'): [23, 'n/a',54,7,32,76],
        ('possible','possible'):[100,100,100,100,100,100]
        })
```

I have 5 upper level indices and 25 lower level ones. I'm wondering if it's possible to only refer to the top ones in

```
no4 = (df.loc[:, (top level indices),(bottom level indices)] == 'n/a').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I think in row with index `1` is typo - not `92` but `96`.

Comment: Hi jezrael. Actually, it should be 92 because I want to subtract 4 for every 'n/a' occurrence in a given row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can checking values by mask with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). Last [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) all values `n/a` to `0`:

Check values values with `n/a` and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) them:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
no4 = (df.loc[:, idx[('A', 'B'), ('a', 'b')]] == 'n/a').sum(axis=1) 
print no4
0    0
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Check if sum are equal `0` (it means there are `n/a` values):

```
mask = no4 != 0
print mask
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Substract `4` times `no4`:

```
df.loc[mask, idx['possible', 'possible']] -= no4 * 4
df.replace({'n/a':0}, inplace=True)
print df
    A   B possible
    a   b possible
0  23  23    100.0
1   0   0     92.0
2  54  54    100.0
3   7   0     96.0
4  32  32    100.0
5  76  76    100.0
```

EDIT:

I found more simplier solution - mask is not necessary, becaue you substract `0` if `n/a`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[:, idx[('A', 'B'), ('a', 'b')]] == 'n/a').sum(axis=1) * 4
0    0
1    8
2    0
3    4
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64

df.loc[:, idx['possible', 'possible']] -= 
(df.loc[:, idx[('A', 'B'), ('a', 'b')]] == 'n/a').sum(axis=1) * 4
df.replace({'n/a':0}, inplace=True)
print df
    A   B possible
    a   b possible
0  23  23      100
1   0   0       92
2  54  54      100
3   7   0       96
4  32  32      100
5  76  76      100
```

EDIT1: If you need select only tom indices - see [using slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
(df.loc[:, idx[(top level indices),:]] == 'n/a').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation! Only one thing: it should subtract 4 for every column for which there is a 'n/a' in the row.

Comment: Is possible that `n/a` are only in column `(A,a)` and not in `(B,b)` ?

Comment: It might occur that way. It depends on the data at a given time. There may be multiple 'n/a' occurrences per row and/or per column.

Comment: Thanks. Is always in last column `int`? Because now I get `float`.

Comment: It's float. No need for int.

Comment: Sorry, now I have to completely change solution. Please check it.

Comment: Sorry for the hassle. I'll check when I get back to my computer tonight. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried your last edit, but I got this: IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: ops, typo. I forget `idx`

Comment: Okay, it works on my sample data for this post. But for my real data, I keep getting: KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)' even after I try df.reset_index()

Comment: Check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex) - you need sortedness.

Comment: I got it. On to the next error, but thanks for your thorough responses, as always.

Comment: I have posted a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096398/pandas-multi-index-subtract-from-value-based-on-value-in-other-column-part-2